# LLVM not recognizing unnamed_addr

Tags: c++, c, linux, llvm, clang

To test LLVM's functionality, I wrote the following simple program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf( "Hello World!\n" );

    return 0;
}
```

And then compiled it to LLVM IR by typing `clang -S -emit-llvm main.c -o main.ll`. The generated code in main.ll was the following.

```
; ModuleID = 'main.c'
target datalayout = "e-p:64:64:64-i1:8:8-i8:8:8-i16:16:16-i32:32:32-i64:64:64-f32:32:32-f64:64:64-v64:64:64-v128:128:128-a0:0:64-s0:64:64-f80:128:128-n8:16:32:64"
target triple = "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"

@.str = private unnamed_addr constant [14 x i8] c"Hello World!\0A\00"

define i32 @main() nounwind {
  %1 = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 0, i32* %1
  %2 = call i32 (i8*, ...)* @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([14 x i8]* @.str, i32 0, i32 0))
  ret i32 0
}

declare i32 @printf(i8*, ...)
```

Then when I tried to compile the IR code (in main.ll) to native executable binary, by typing `llc main.ll -o main.s && gcc main.s -o main`, I got the following error.

```
llc: main.ll:5:17: error: expected 'global' or 'constant'
@.str = private unnamed_addr constant [14 x i8] c"Hello World!\0A\00"
```

However, If I remove `unnamed_addr` from main.ll, it does get compiled. So my question is what is wrong with `unnamed_addr`. Why it is not compiling with it? Is this maybe because I'm using incompatible versions of clang and llvm?

Answer (score 2):

The `unnamed_addr` attribute was [introduced in LLVM 2.9](http://llvm.org/releases/2.9/docs/ReleaseNotes.html).

Could it be that your clang is from 2.9 or newer, while your `llc` is from 2.8 or older?

Comment: Yes I think that is the problem. My clang is 2.9 for sure. So I suspect that my llc is 2.8. By the way, is there any other thing that was introduced in LLVM 2.9, besides unnamed_addr?

Comment: @MetallicPriest: each LLVM release comes with release notes. I linked to the 2.9 release notes in the answer. The following is a list of all releases with links for their downloads, docs and release notes: http://llvm.org/releases/

Comment: Thanks Eli. Do you know of anyway to make clang generate IR for an older version of LLVM, so through a flag maybe I can instruct clang 2.9 to generate LLVM 2.8 IR code.

Comment: @MetallicPriest: I wouldn't bother. Just download, build and install locally (if you have no root access) the latest & greatest LLVM & Clang. If your machine isn't too old it will take you 15-20 minutes

Comment: Yes I have installed llvm-2.9 now. Working perfectly :)!

Comment: @MetallicPriest: that's good to hear. As a general advice, it is always recommended to install LLVM & Clang together since they're linked together (more specifically, Clang links in some parts of LLVM)